# HTML bolding not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I writing an auto complete control and I'm to the point where I'm building a `<ul>` with the results of a Webservice.  I go ahead and try to apply my bolding on the server and return it as string to the client to be just injected into a new `<li>`

My problem is the bolding isn't rendering it looks like it should be but it isn't.

Here is what I'm doing

```
$this.append($('<li>').html(obj.value))
```

In this example:  $this = UL as a jquery object.  and

```
obj.value = "<b>H</b><b>S</b>OU"
```

The firebug shows it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <b>H</b>
    <b>S</b>
    OU
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:**  It DOES render in IE but not in Chrome/Firefox, oddly enough.

Comment: What does firebug say about the computed css?

Comment: Are those two characters not supposed to be bold? Or are they not displaying as bold, but the HTML is correct?

Comment: No they are supposed to be bold, but they are not showing up bold

Comment: And the computed style show a font-weight of 400

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output HTML looks right to me?

Perhaps you have a CSS directive suppressing the usual visualisation of bold text. Inspect the element with text `H` (also in Firebug) and see what styles are being applied to it.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that would suppress it.  And I think that if that was the case it wouldn't work in IE the way it does right now.  In IE the bolding is being rendered correctly.

Comment: @Collin: A live example would be helpful.

Comment: @Tomalak I made a working example but it works :) I am using a CSS reset found here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ this is the issue

Comment: @Collin: If you can't reproduce the issue, then I don't think we're going to be able to help you solve it.

Comment: Is there a way around using the font: inherit tag in the css reset... that appears to be what is causing the issue

Comment: @Collin: Offhand I couldn't say. I suggest trying alternative "CSS resets" until you find one that works, then compare. :)

Comment: @Collin you could reset the bold in css (after the css reset of course) b { font-weight: 700; }

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you have a CSS reset that removes the bold value of `<b>`.

If this is the case however, it would mean that all your `<b>` don't behave as expected.

Comment: Not so; such a directive could be dependent upon the element's ancestry. Consider the selector `ul > li > b`.

Comment: @Tomalak, yes but in this case, it would mean that the author willingly removed formatting of B specifically for this instance and then forgot about it. Not too likely. Much more likely is one big reset that was cut and pasted in the css file.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: As you said yourself, all such `b` would be affected. `ul > li > b` may affect styling _elsewhere_ in the page; it may not be that such a selector was meant specifically for _this_ instance.

Comment: @Tomalak: I may be wrong, but I expect someone capable of writing `ul > li > b` to understand that it can apply somewhere unexpected. A selector is different from a reset in that resets get shared and reused whereas selectors are usually written specifically for the page.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: Sure, but the simple fact is that _something is wrong_, or the question would not have been posted. Therefore, assumptions that nobody involved has made a mistake seem a little far-fetched. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: Where was that assumption made?

Comment: @Sylverdrag: You "expect someone capable of" X "to understand that it can apply somewhere expected", and not to have made a mistake. The implication that the error cannot be here seems weird to me.